# automatically converting xml format from LibGlade to GtkBuilder

Tags: gtk, glade

I've found 2 ways of converting from an old GTK+ UI xml format (using Libglade) to the new format (using the built-in GtkBuilder). One is using Glade 3 Interface Builder (Save As button), and another is using gtk-builder-convert. They give different outputs, so I would like to know which one to trust more.

Comment: What is the difference in the output? Which one is more correct? You should trust that one.

Comment: @ptomato, I found that Glade Interface Builder removes "tooltip-text" from the xml. Maybe it's a bug. `gtk-builder-convert` converts MenuBar and MenuItem to UIManager.

Comment: removing `tooltip-text` is probably a bug. You should report it at bugzilla.gnome.org. I would use Save As in Glade 3 and add the tooltip text yourself until the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `gtk-builder-convert` is less buggy than the two. Glade 3 screws up the xml output even when making a small edit without even doing a convert (Saving to old glade format).